# Bootstrap Table and striped row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know the difference b/w bootstrap `.table` and `.table-striped`?

I didn't see any difference

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_striped&stacked=h

See these two links

Comment: Class `.table-striped` has zebra-stripes, focus on all even and odd rows.

Comment: Thnx. I undertood it

Answer (score 0):

> The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table.

The table alternates white and gray lines if it's  striped.

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

The table-stripped has a stripped pattern on the `<td>` for better reading. If you look carefully enough you will notice that the `<td>` differs.

Comment: Thank You for the answer